# Adobe ColdFusion, CFGrid is not populating after get login an navigate the page,

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfgrid

I tried to bind a `CFGrid` in ColdFusion through a CFC function which works correctly, but after login when I tried to surf to the page the `CFGrid` does not get populated with any records.

Here is my `grid.cfm` code:

```
<cfform name="GridForm">
    <cfgrid format="html" name="UserGrid" pagesize="10" selectmode="row" bind="cfc:Consumer.getUserinfo({cfgridpage},{cfgridpagesize},{cfgridsortcolumn},{cfgridsortdirection})">             

    <cfgridcolumn name="FirstName" width="300" header="FirstName" />
    <cfgridcolumn name="LastName" width="180" header="LastName" />
    <cfgridcolumn name="UserName" width="120" header="UserName" />
    <cfgridcolumn name="Age" width="60" header="Age" />
    </cfgrid>
    <br/>
</cfform>
```

And here is my cfc function:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cffunction name="getUserInfo" access="remote" returntype="struct" >
        <cfargument name="page" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="pageSize" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="gridsortcolumn" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="gridsortdirection" required="true" />

        <cfif arguments.gridsortcolumn eq "">
        <cfset arguments.gridsortcolumn = "FirstName" />
        <cfset arguments.gridsortdirection = "asc" />
        </cfif>

        <cfquery name="GetUser" datasource="MyDatabase" >
        select      *
        from        UserInfo
        order by    #arguments.gridsortcolumn# #arguments.gridsortdirection#
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn queryconvertforgrid(GetUser, page, pagesize) />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Why doesn't this grid get populated after the login?

Comment: I fixed some typos and missing brackets in your code.  I am assuming those only existed in what you posted here, and not actually in your code.  Right?  Particularly there was a missing `{` in your `bind` statement.

Comment: Step 1 - what happens if you invoke the function without using bind syntax and dump the returned value?

Comment: @Miguel-F thanks for the comment. Please ignore the missing braces, the real code is working while i use to navigate page without login.but after login the Grid does not filled with data.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for you valuable comment, sir i am novice to cold fusion , i didn't tried to invoke that function without bind expresson and i wrote this functoin works while i navigate the page without login, but after login the role  and session is created by application and then when i use to Surf that page the grid does populate it self with records. and if i replace the bind expression with query one it works after login too

Comment: @Miguel-F no its same while i use bind expression and check the grid after login.its not working

Comment: @Sonu, you are never too new to learn good habits.  Take baby steps.  First, make sure your query works, which you have done.  Then make sure your cfc works.  Then move on the binding part.

Comment: @DanBracuk when i debug it i found Exception: parseJSON File: http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js , could you please help me to get rid off from it

Comment: guys i am still on this problem please advice me to solve it, why after being login , grid not able to display records

Comment: If the grid is working in one scenario versus another then you need to examine the values in both to see what is different. Check your form values when logged in and not logged in. Also check the values in your cfc when logged in and not logged in. Since there is also client-side code being generated here you should also compare the generated source code under both scenarios. Please report back with this info.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the developer tools / javascript console in Chrome.  Turn on log XMLHTTPRequests.  Then, next time you reload your app, the console will show you all of the ajax calls your app is making and if they succeed or fail.

If you have a failing request you can right click on it and open it in a new tab to see the error details just like you would normally trouble shoot a problem.